# Is Item Response Theory (IRT) a form of reinforcement learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, item-response-theory, item-analysis

I was doing studies in reinforcement learning and trying to apply it in Computerised Adaptive Testing (CAT). While learning IRT, I felt it is similar to behaviour of RL setting - receiving feedback and adjusting parameters(or learning) in each cycle.

Is Item Response Theory (IRT) a form of reinforcement learning? Can I know the differences if any.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this any? We prefer threads that don't amount to just "Yes", or "No". Is there something confusing you about these? How did this question arise? Etc.

Comment: I was doing some studies in reinforcement learning and trying to apply it in Computerised Adaptive Testing(CAT). While learning IRT, I felt it is similar to behaviour of RL setting - Learning and adjusting parameters in each cycle.

Comment: More [active learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_learning_(machine_learning)) I suggest. But if you expand on your analogy it will be easier to say how CAT and RL might be usefully related.

Comment: How exactly do you believe IRT "adjusts" parameters? Note- IRT has a Bayesian interpretation, but is not a Bayesian procedure *per se*, not even approximate. Though frequentist inference is not without a means to incorporate prior information (data), either by weighting, initial conditions, offsets, and/or sequential analysis... My experience with IRT is that it is a batch analysis for evaluation of a test or a survey instrument and so does not adjust parameters.

Comment: You might want to specify what you mean by reinforcement learning, esp. when you are relating it to things from psychometrics, like IRT and CAT. My PhD is in psychometrics and, in psychology, reinforcement learning is something else completely.  When I read the question it seemed to make no sense, but I Googled.

Answer (score 4):

**Preamble**

As I am sure you are already aware, Item Response Theory (IRT) is an umbrella term for a family of statistical models used to model the relationship between a test-taker's latent ability and their probability of correctly answering specific items (questions). Computer Adaptive Testing (CAT) is a form of assessment where tests are dynamically tailored to the test-taker's ability level. CAT assessments, unlike fixed-form assessments, select questions$^1$ to match the test-taker's estimated ability level. The link between IRT and CAT is that the latter uses IRT-calibrated item banks and leverages the properties of IRT parameter estimates to both stop testing and to select questions. Whereas Reinforcement Learning (RL), on the other hand, is a type of machine learning (ML) where an agent learns to make decisions by performing actions in an environment to achieve some goals.

**Answer**

Now to your questions.

> I was doing studies in reinforcement learning and trying to apply it in Computerized Adaptive Testing (CAT). While learning IRT, I felt it is similar to behavior of RL setting - receiving feedback and adjusting parameters(or learning) in each cycle.

Yes, you are correct in pointing out that both IRT and RL use feedback. RL involves a continuous feedback loop where the agent's actions influence the future state of the environment, and the environment's feedback influences the agent's future actions. Similarly, in IRT, feedback is used to update item parameter estimates. However, this similarity that RL has with IRT may be extended to many other statistical problems, as statistical problems with no closed-form solution typically require feedback to arrive at a solution.

> Is Item Response Theory (IRT) a form of reinforcement learning? Can I know the differences if any.

I would not say this, though I believe @conjugateprior was on to something when they suggested -

> you expand on your analogy it will be easier to say how CAT and RL might be usefully related

So while I would not say either IRT or CAT is subsumed within RL (or vice-versa), they can be applied jointly to solve problems. For example, recently Xiao et al. (2023) developed a Deep Reinforcement Learning (DRL) algorithm to create individualized learning plans for traits believed to be continuous. Their approach used IRT as the measurement model and a DRL algorithm to find optimal learning paths.

$^1$ Note that this is an overgeneralization as CAT assessments differ with regards to how many questions are initially presented before subsequent questions are adaptively administered.

**References**

Li, X., Xu, H., Zhang, J., & Chang, H. H. (2023). Deep reinforcement learning for adaptive learning systems. Journal of Educational and Behavioral Statistics, 48(2), 220-243.

Comment: +1, however, in the first part of your "answer" I think you mean "CAT and RL use reinforcement".  IRT doesn't necessarily use it.